# pull to refresh doesn't work in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to try the refresh in react native .

I found this example but I didn't work for me;Imissed something ,can anyOne help me

```
import { ScrollView, RefreshControl } from 'react-native';

class RefreshableList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      refreshing: false,
    };
  }

  _onRefresh = () => {
    this.setState({refreshing: true});
    fetchData().then(() => {
      this.setState({refreshing: false});
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
            onRefresh={this._onRefresh}
          />
        }
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Explain what "doesn't work" means a little more. Does the state not update? Does the data not fetch?

Comment: They told me that they can't found  fetchData()

Comment: I don't see it defined anywhere. What do you expect it to be?

Comment: I don't know , this was my question in stackOverfloww .I'm waiting for any help

Comment: Did you copy this from an example or something? `fetchData` just appears to be a function that returns a promise (or at least that's what your code expects it to be). But I don't see it included in your code, so it makes sense why it would break.

Comment: yeah ,I found this example on internet like this https://www.google.com/amp/s/reactnativeforyou.com/how-to-add-pull-down-to-refresh-feature-in-react-native/amp/

Comment: Maybe you should try a more complete tutorial. Here's the same example from the [react docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/refreshcontrol) with more detail.